# Spring Mail - ImapIdleChannelAdapter Receiving some mails multiple times and some only once

Tags: spring, spring-integration, imap, email

I am using ImapIdleChannelAdapter for receiving incoming mails. I have a listener configured to get informed about any incoming mail, that further invokes an async method and passes over message processing to it.

The problem that i am facing is that it is receiving the same mail multiple times. I am not sure why it is doing that.

This is my config

```
@Bean
ImapIdleChannelAdapter mailAdapter() {
    String user = getMail().get("inbound.secure.user");
    String pwd = getMail().get("inbound.secure.pwd");
    String hostname = getMail().get("inbound.secure.host");
    String port = getMail().get("inbound.secure.imap.port");
    String protocol = getMail().get("inbound.secure.imap.protocol");
    String host = protocol + "://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/INBOX";

    ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = getReceiver(host, user, pwd);

    ImapIdleChannelAdapter mailChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(mailReceiver);
    mailChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
    mailChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(mailChannel());

    return mailChannelAdapter;
}

private ImapMailReceiver getReceiver(String host, String user, String pwd) {
    ImapMailReceiver jobSeekerMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(host);
    jobSeekerMailReceiver.setSimpleContent(true);
    jobSeekerMailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
    jobSeekerMailReceiver.setJavaMailAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pwd);
        }
    });
    jobSeekerMailReceiver.afterPropertiesSet();

    jobSeekerMailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
    jobSeekerMailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);

    return jobSeekerMailReceiver;
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel mailChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

My listener is as

```
    @MessageEndpoint
public class MailListener {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailListener.class);
    private final MailOrganiserService mailOrganiserService;
    @Autowired
    public MailListener(MailOrganiserService mailOrganiserService) {
        this.mailOrganiserService = mailOrganiserService;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mailChannel")
    public void handleSecureMessage(Message message) {
            String sender = message.getFrom()[0].toString();
            Address[] recipients = message.getAllRecipients();
            logger.info("handle secure message from {} to {}", sender, recipients);
            this.mailOrganiserService.processIncomingMessageAsync(message);
            logger.info("returning from handing over mail from {} to {}", sender, recipients);
    }
}
```

Another observation that i made is that although i have configured an ImapIdleChannelAdapter, i see regular logs with

```
attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
```

This looks like polling behavior instead of event driven.

I am using the following version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImapMailReceiver` needs to be defined as a `@Bean`.

Otherwise the folder is opened in read only mode.

Set `mail.debug=true` in the javamail properties to see the IMAP protocol exchanges.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I was hoping you would respond to this :) I will define receiver as @Bean and try, but there are mails that are processed only once.  I think the split could be about 60% mails processed once and 40 % processed multiple times.  I also monitored the mailbox and could see mails being marked as read.

Comment: mail.debug is always your friend.